# How to copy/paste 'int' content from webpage

Tags: java, clipboarddata

I want to copy/paste an **int** from a website, I know it's a very good way, even a non-proper one but i didn't find better

With Java.awt.Robot I go at the good position on page, make 2 clics to select the content, and then make a ctrl+C to add it to the clipboard

But then I have to get back the value which is an **int**

```
public static String getAsText() {
        String clipText = "";
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(null);
        if ((contents != null) && contents.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
            try {
                clipText = (String) contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
            } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ClipboardTransfert.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ClipboardTransfert.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return clipText;
    }
```

This works for String, but not int. I tried with :

- `DataFlavor intFlavor = new DataFlavor(int.class, "Integer");` but Exception at `isDataFlavorSupported`
- Change type method to int, also to `clipText` variable, but not working
- usual casting methods but not working, it prints the String (to be sure => if i do `theString + 1`, I get : `theString1`)

So how to ?

Comment: so you are getting the desired number as a String at the moment?

Comment: Yes exactly, and Integer.valueOf() does nothing

Comment: try Integer.parseInt(yourString)

Comment: @TomK This is equivalent to Integer.valueof() and it enters in "usual casting methods" as I said in my question I've already tried

Comment: i just copied your code, copied a number into my clipboard, changed the functions return type to int and made the last line return Integer.parseInt(clipText); and its working without any problems.

Comment: @TomK what is "this works" for you ? If you System.out.print(value+159) does it really add 159 to your value or concatenate the two ? because for me it concatenates

Comment: i am returning an int from the function, so value+159 results in 160

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136472/discussion-between-azro-and-tom-k).

Comment: Stop .. I don't why but now i works ... I add brackets, i remove them and it's working, so sorry for unuseful post ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding your problem, but can't you just [parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) it? Like this:

```
int clipboardContent = Integer.parseInt(contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor));
```

Comment: This is equivalent to Integer.valueof() and it enters in "usual casting methods" as I said in my question I've already tried

Comment: What do you mean by "it prints the string"? Can you show the code where it prints it?